# Display d3.js wrongly in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I got a problem that cause in `bootstrap` `modal`, I put a `d3.js` donut chart, but it display wrongly like this.
[image]

The number would overlap with the text, however, it will work perfectly without `modal`.

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal" id="portfolioModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
            <div class="container">
                ...
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                         <div id="pieChart"></div>
                    </div>                
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you facing a modal width problem.

In [Bootstrap 3.1.1](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes) they added modal-lg and modal-sm classes. You control the modal size using @media queries like they do. This is a more global way of controlling the modal size.

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.modal-lg  
{
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px; /* control height here if its needed */
}
```

One sample for you

```
<!-- Large modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Small modal -->
 <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps my friend, If you could provide a JSFIDDLE file would be ease our work =)

Comment: It's solve part of my question, after  I modify a little bit, it work perfectly, thanks.